# Prestashop 1.7, where notifications are stored?

Tags: notifications, prestashop

I've got a little problem with a notification in Prestashop 1.7.

It's displaying like this:

```
"Brak dostępnych adresów. <a href="https://morelowaszafa.pl/adres">Dodaj nowy adres</a>"
```

It should be displayed like this: "Brak dostępnych adresów. [Dodaj nowy adres](https://morelowaszafa.pl/adres)"

But somehow it's showing all the anchor... i found out that in page source there is `&lt;` instead of `<` and `&gt;` instead of `>`

But i've got no idea where to find it and change.
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit file `themes/classic/templates/_partials/notifications.tpl`

and replace:

```
<li>{$notif}</li>
```

with:

```
<li>{$notif nofilter}</li>
```

*Source: https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/pull/7554/files*

Comment: That works also, if you like i can accept your answer, just edit it with the name of file to edit and line where to do so.

Comment: I like it because it has been the official commit :) https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/pull/7554

Comment: Yes it looks more clean :)

Answer (score 0):

I've found an answer how to solve it.

In themes\classic\templates_partials\notifications.tpl

Edit line 46 from:

```
<li>{$notif}</li>
```

to:

```
<li>{$notif|@print_r|substr:0:-1}</li>
```

Answer found here: http://forge.prestashop.com/browse/BOOM-3033